# Evaluating line integrals given multiple paths

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Evaluate $$ \int_c  (\ln(1+x^5)+1/2 y^2)dx+xydy $$ for the following sub-paths that together make up the closed path C.

a.) $y=x^2$ from $(-1,1)$ to $(1,1)$,

b.) $x=1$ from $(1,1)$ to $(1,3)$,

c.) $x^2+y^2=10$, from $(1,3)$ to $(-1,3)$

d.) $x=-1$ from $(-1,3)$ to $(-1,1)$.

I have my calc final coming up and I'm 90% certain this type of question will be on it. It's from my old quiz and I had no idea how to do it.. too many things, just super confused. what I DO know is that this is a conservative function, which in turn means that the path does not matter (which cuts all the work down tremendously) ...

What I don't know, is where I start.. and where I end. I don't have the slightest clue on how to do this problem. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can go by (but in the long run...)

you can perameterize each of the contours, and do 4 integrals.

Or you can apply Green's theorem.

over a closed contour

$\oint P(x,y) dx + Q(x,y) dy = \iint (\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}) \;dA$

With $P$ and $Q$ as above $\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = y-y = 0$ you have a conservative force.

A third way that I hadn't considered when I strated.

Comment: thank you thats all i was looking for.

Comment: I see now that you knew that it was a conservative force.  In which case the paths are irrelevant, all that matters are the end points.  And if the endpoints are the same (closed contour) then the integral is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something is wrong with your exercise.

The vector field is conservative in the half-plane $D:=\{(x,y):x>-1\}$ with a scalar potential 
$$U(x,y)=\int\ln(1+x^5)dx+\frac{xy^2}{2}.$$
If $C$ is a closed curve contained in $D$ then the integral along $C$ is zero.

In your case $C$ is NOT contained in $D$. In part d) $x=-1$ and $\log(1+x^5)$ is NOT defined there because $1+(-1)^5=0$. This means that you can't evaluate it (or apply Green's Theorem).

Comment: is Green's theorem possible here? i believe that is what my professor is aiming for since the work will be super long.

Comment: @Ryanori I don't think you can apply Green's theorem. See my edited answer.

Comment: yeah i understand what you mean.. but im sure my professor doesnt want us to do 4 different integrals in one small portion of the test. Maybe an error on his part? i hope..

Comment: @Ryanori Maybe an error or maybe your professor wants to see if you check the hypothesis before applying the Green's theorem.